# The meaning of **homomorphic preimage **

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

We are working on commutative Ring Theory and their modules. While studying a paper, we saw the concept "homomorphic preimage of an $R$-module". I want to know the meaning of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M$ being an $R$-module, a homomorphic preimage of $M$ is the preimage of $M$ under a homomorphism $N \to M$ for some $R$-module $N$.